# Issue in Recuring Journey Remainder Path

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

for a particular Recuring Journey, an Update contact was kept in the Remainder Path by creating a new version after 10 days of activating the Journey. The Remainder path is now considering the entire audience that is present in the Target DE instead of considering the day to day contacts entering the particular Journey Flow? Pls do clarify on the same

Answer (score 0):

A remainder path leads to a update contact activity only applies to those entries who flow through that path not all the rows in the entry source DE, so in the decision split, any entry not meet the criteria for other paths will automatically flow into remainder path.

So if you have a update contact activity, it will try to find the entry record in target DE (the one you setup in Contact Builder > Data Designer), identified by ContactKey value and update the field you selected. But if you don't have that entry in Target DE (Contact Data), it won't do anything. It will certainly NOT updating all the audiences in the DE.